# Cannot check/uncheck a checkbox on the selected row of a CheckboxTableViewer

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

Working with Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7 and Java 7, I have built a table from the `CheckboxTableViewer` class like this:

```
tableViewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList ( groupTable, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION
    | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.VIRTUAL );
```

The viewer has two listeners, implementing respectively `ISelectionChangedListener` and `ICheckStateListener`. Everything works fine excepted the following:

I cannot change the checkbox state on the selected row. Is this a known issue or should I add something to the definition of the viewer?

Comment: Possibly something to do with the `SWT.VIRTUAL` flag, not sure how checkbox tables work with that.

Answer (score -1):

Enable the table you are working on

e.g. `groupTable.setEnabled(true);`